# Переход на заданную Activity при скрытии приложения

Tags: android, android-studio, activity

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при скрытии приложения, или блокировке телефона совершить переход на заданную Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак не сделать то что вы хотите. У активности есть много состояний:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При сворачивании приложения оно переводится в неактивное состояние и выполнять действия не будет вероятнее всего. Есть один вариант как это сделать - при сворачивании приложения вы ничего не делайте, а потом при восстановлении приложения из свернутых вы выполняете переход на нужную вам активность. Функция восстановления приложения называется `onResume()` как -то так:

```
 override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
       Intent k = new Intent(Activity_1.this, Activity_2.class);
startActivity(k);
    }
```

в итоге при возврате в приложение вы будете переходить на нужную активность, но при первом открытии приложения вы тоже будете переходить на нужную активность а это наверное не очень правильно. Значит вы должны объявить глобальную переменную которая будет по умолчанию false и дальше после работы в приложении вы переводите эту переменную в состояние true и при проверке в функции `onResume()` вы будете проверять значение этой переменной. Вот к примеру, есть еще одна функция отвечающая за сворачивание приложения `onStop()`:

```
override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()

    }
```

в этой функции вы можете переводить глобальную переменную в состояние true для того чтобы при возврате переходить на нужную вам активность. Либо как-то иначе реализовать то что вам нужно. Но в свернутом состоянии насколько я знаю приложение делать ничего не будет, максимум что можно сделать это фоновый процесс который будет выполнять вашу задачу, но я не уверен что это правильное решение. Вот [источник](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/lifecycle.php) где расписано про жизненный цикл активности.